# Build VueJS storage plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I need to create a `plugin` that would watch `data` of the `component`, and synchronize it with a kind of storage, such as `localStorage` - it does not matter.

When `mounted` or`created` this component will retrieve the storage values, and write them in `data`

Ultimately, I want the data from the interface did not disappear after reloading the page.
`vuex-persist` and like this plugins  working with data from Vuex, when I want to work with these components.

I began to create a `plugin`:

```
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      computed: {
        watchedComponents() {
          return this._data // Is there some other way to obtain the component data ???
        }
      },
      watch: {
        watchedComponents: {
          deep: true, // For watching nestead changes
          handler() {
            // At this point I start receive recursion errors.
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Share your vision solutions.
I would be grateful to any attention and assistance.

Comment: This question is not well suited for this plattform. Please try to ask specific questions  that allow for a concrete answer rather than asking for such broad implementation examples. Try to work as far as you can get - then ask when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You will love that this already exists.

Independed of whether you want to use it or build your own plugin, you can learn a lot from [vuex-persis](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#readme).